# How to create multiple directory in django template folder?

Tags: python, django

I want to change php website into django. In php, we have controller and view folder. Inside view, I have many folder in view.

```
View
  --- Users
        --- user1.ctp
        --- user2.ctp
  --- Layouts
        --- layout1.ctp
        --- layout2.ctp
```

Now I am using django this is how my directory looks

```
MyProject
     --- myapp
           --- views.py
           --- urls.py
           --- migrations
                  --- __pycache__
           --- static
                 --- myapp
                       --- mycss.css
           --- templates
                 --- myapp
                      --- Users
                            --- user1.html
                            --- user2.html
                      --- Layouts
                            --- layout1.html
                            --- layout2.html
     --- MyProject
```

Whenever I am putting user1.html inside /templates/myapp, I am able to render but I want to put Users related file in Users folder. I am getting

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
myapp/Layouts/layout1.html
```

urls.py (Inside myapp)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from . import views,login

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index),
]
```

urls.py (Inside MyProject)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request,'myapp/Layouts/layout1.html')
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-j+_1ue45jw(f8u0utf*uh&s1$j-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'python_test.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mypage',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Please show us your view file

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add view.py. Now I edited.

Comment: Can you also show your `TEMPLATES` and `INSTALLED_APPS` settings?

Comment: @anonymous which template is not being found - what is the full error?

Comment: Please share your settings file

Comment: @IainShelvington I have templates folder inside myapp only and that templates folder is not found.

Comment: There is no index.html in your Layouts directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your additional templates in settings.py like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
ADDITIONAL_TEMPLATE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'path/to/template')
# add as many as you required
```

Use your template dirs as following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # add your all template dirs here
        'DIRS': [TEMP_DIR, ADDITIONAL_TEMPLATE, ... ...],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # add your context processor here
            ],
        },
    },
]
```