# TemplateDoesNotExist at /fund_me issue

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

**I have went through the answers to similar question on this site but nothing seems to work as i receive the same error message each time. Help would be greatly appreciated. ERROR MESSAGE ON THE BOTTOM**

**directory tree:**

[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sX2n.png)

**urls.py in fund_proj:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from fund_me import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("fund_me", include("fund_me.urls")),
]
```

**urls.py in fund_me:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path("", views.say_hello)]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def say_hello(request):
    context = {"name": "joe"}
    return render(request, "fund_me/templates/hello_page.html", context)
```

**settings.py (relevant code)**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), "./fund_me/templates/"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**error message and traceback**

[error msg and traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmnM.png)

Comment: Once I faced this problem, Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916309/how-to-create-multiple-directory-in-django-template-folder

Comment: @anonymous I have added 

ADDITIONAL_TEMPLATE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "fund_proj/fund_me/templates/")

and added ADDITIONAL_TEMPLATE  to "DIRS" but the error persists. Thank you for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return render(request, "fund_me/templates/hello_page.html", context)
```

write:

```
return render(request, "hello_page.html", context)
```